# Problem with the print statement in Python

Tags: python

What it's wrong with this code?

```
from math import*

def euclidean_distance(x,y):

    return sqrt(sum(pow(a-b,2) for a, b in zip(x, y)))

print euclidean_distance([0,3,4,5],[7,6,3,-1])
```

This is a Python code that I'm running under Windows.

I don't see anything wrong, but, despite of that, the Python interpreter produce a syntax error in the print statement.

Comment: What is the syntax error message?

Comment: There was not any problem for me. If you use python versions upper than 3, bring the print statement into parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

I couldnt comment, so I am posting as answer. You need to put () for print. Try

```
from math import*

def euclidean_distance(x,y):

    return sqrt(sum(pow(a-b,2) for a, b in zip(x, y)))
#added parentheses here
print(euclidean_distance([0,3,4,5],[7,6,3,-1]))
```

Comment: Since he was getting error, I assumed he was using 3

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. Online tutorials use old versions of languages, then languages change and they don't update. 
Thank you to all, you saved me from a mental illness!